# deserializing the content of a json array in a class shows null values using gson

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, gson

I am trying to deserialize the content of a json array with name topics.
after deserialing into the pojo, the topics array keeps printing null even though everything seems fine

//entry model

```
public class MainRequest {

    private  String bookId;
    private List<topics> topics; //called as a list based on the json structure
    
    }
```

//topics model

```
public class topics {
    private String DESCRIPTION;
    private String INDEX;
}
```

the two models is executed in a controller this way

```
@PostMapping(path = "/do-library-request", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> process(@RequestBody List<MainRequest> mainRequest,
                                                 HttpServletRequest request
    ) {

        Gson gsons = new Gson();
        
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Request: {0}", gsons.toJson(mainRequest));
        
        //out from logger
        {"bookId":"155","topics":[{},{}]} // topics are null and this is the problem
                
        .......
```

how can I print the value of the topics is the challenge

```
[{

       "bookId":"155",       

       "topics":[

          {

             "DESCRIPTION":"Little Beginnings",

             "INDEX":"3455"

          },

          {

             "DESCRIPTION":"Nostalgic moments",

             "INDEX":"1234567"

          }

       ],
```

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character and variable names should start with lover case properties

Comment: done as advised and the issue still persists....

Comment: Do you have getter , setter and noargs constructors?

Comment: I have created a smal test program and it works fine `String mainRequest = "[{\r\n" + "\r\n" + "       \"bookId\":\"155\",       \r\n" + "\r\n"+ "       \"topics\":[\r\n" + "\r\n" + "          {\r\n" + "\r\n"+ "             \"DESCRIPTION\":\"Little Beginnings\",\r\n" + "\r\n"+ "             \"INDEX\":\"3455\"\r\n" + "\r\n" + "},\r\n" + "\r\n" + "{\r\n"+ "\r\n" + "             \"DESCRIPTION\":\"Nostalgic moments\",\r\n" + "\r\n"+ "\"INDEX\":\"1234567\"\r\n" + "\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "\r\n" + "]}]"; Gson gsons = new Gson();

  System.out.println(gsons.fromJson(mainRequest, List.class));

 }`

Comment: prints out `[{bookId=155, topics=[{DESCRIPTION=Little Beginnings, INDEX=3455}, {DESCRIPTION=Nostalgic moments, INDEX=1234567}]}]`

Comment: I am using lombok, I will remove it and add the getter and setter manually

Comment: You do not need it. I am also added lombok annotations

Comment: I would try to change name of property `DESCRIPTION` to `description` and add the `@SerializedName` or `JsonProperty` annotation (depends on if you are using gson or jackson in spring boot

Comment: I am using gson, please u can post as answer for better readability

Comment: No because i do not know if it solves your problem

Comment: because u can see that me controller takes this - 
@RequestBody List<MainRequest> mainRequest,

Comment: more reason why I needed u to post an actual answer

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: still same issuee bro

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable names of class topic to lower case and add the `SerializedName` annotation

```
@Data
public class topics {
    @SerializedName("DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("INDEX")
    private String index;
}
```

This should solve your problem.
BTW: especialy at this point it is important to follow the java naming convetions